# AAD PowerShell v2 Add-MsolRoleMember equivalent

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory

I try to switch from the AAD v1 PowerShell Module (MSOnline) to **v2**.

I can't find an equivalent cmdlet for `Add-MsolRoleMember` to assign a role to a **service principal** (not an user). Like:

```
Add-MsolRoleMember -RoleObjectId 88d8e3e3-8f55-4a1e-953a-9b9898b8876b -RoleMemberObjectId 'MyServicePrincipalObjectId' -RoleMemberType servicePrincipal
```

Comment: New-AzureRmRoleAssignment ?

Comment: @4c74356b41 Thats the ARM module, not AAD V2

Comment: ok, i wasn't even aware that exists, how about this one: New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is now called `Add-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember`.

> NAME
>
> ```
> Add-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember
> ```
>
> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
> Add a member to a directory role
> ```

Example:

```
Add-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember -ObjectId <role id> -RefObjectId <service principal object id>
```

The command only expects a directory object id, no matter what its documentation says about adding a *user* to a role.

As noted by @rcabr, you may need to run this first:

```
Enable-AzureADDirectoryRole -RoleTemplateId 88d8e3e3-8f55-4a1e-953a-9b9898b8876b
```

You can then use the resulting object id in the next command.

The command I run:

```
Add-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember -ObjectId afbba7aa-c743-406a-907a-4357c6b13415 -RefObjectId 6e56b47c-4c6e-40f5-aa95-16a0b1cb44fc
```

Comment: I tried the cmdlet but get the following error: `Add-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember : Error occurred while executing AddDirectoryRoleMember 
StatusCode: NotFound
ErrorCode: Request_ResourceNotFound
Message: Resource '<my guid was here>' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.`

Comment: What kind of role are you trying to add the service principal to?

Comment: I tried it with '88d8e3e3-8f55-4a1e-953a-9b9898b8876b' - *Directory Readers*

Comment: I added the command I executed, my object ids will be different, but the first one is for Directory Readers, and the second one is a service principal's object id.

Comment: I double checked that I used the principal's object id (not the application Id and not the object id of the application). Weired. Anyhow, you answerd my question - I will try to figure out whats going wrong here. Thanks again juunas.

Comment: @MartinBrandl, you may need to first execute
`$role = Enable-AzureADDirectoryRole -RoleTemplateId 88d8e3e3-8f55-4a1e-953a-9b9898b8876b`
Then, `Add-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember -ObjectId $role.ObjectId -RefObjectId <yourAppObjectId>`

Comment: @rcabr Thanks for the hint!